# How to prevent two root windows from coming up when I start Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, smtp

**Question**

How can I hide the two Tkinter root windows that are popping up in my program? I have tried to use `root.widthdraw()`. [Here is a link to my Pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/TMzQkvW3)

**Background**

I am trying to create a *really* basic email client to learn more about Tkinter and SMTP. I have decided that my program will first create a [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) window where the user will enter their credentials, and if the Server can authenticate them, then the program opens the email send dialogue. Annoyingly, I have not been able to hide the 2 other root windows which open when the program starts up. I have attempted to use `root.widthdraw()` to avoid this issue.

**Relevant Code**

```
#-----Authen is a toplevel class-------------

passcheck = Authen()

root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
root.widthdraw()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create your root window *before* creating any other windows. Otherwise you get exactly what you observe: Tkinter will automatically create a root window the first time you create some other widget, and the you are creating a second one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Python2.7, with the default `tkinter` package, and my `root` object doesn't have a `withdraw()` method. Besides that, you can also just run `mainloop` off the `toplevel` called `passcheck` and it'll save you a window.

```
class Authen(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
```

then:

```
root = Tk()
passcheck = Authen(root) 
root.mainloop()
```

edit: Here's a solution, instead of `Authen` being a `TopLevel`, have it be a `Frame` instead, and pass `root` as it's master. http://pastebin.com/TtnvU0er

Comment: +1 for the partial answer... now how do I get rid of the other one?

Comment: Why not make the `Authen` class a `Frame` instead of a TopLevel, and pass the original `root` object as the master?

Comment: @xxmbabanexx Check out this pastebin with a working example http://pastebin.com/TtnvU0er